# C++ and PEMDAS Order of Precedence/Operations?

Tags: c++

I have a question I was not able to find an answer for, I'm looking for some clarification.

From my understanding, C++ follows PEMDAS, is this correct?

So if I do something like `5/9 * (34/.2)`, it will have a hard time computing this formula due to the fact that the parentheses are at the end and not the front. Is this correct?

When I do `(34/.2) *5/9`, my formula works.

Any tips, pointers, guidance is appreciated. I feel like I'm really lost here.

Comment: Searching "C++ Order of Precedence" yielded [this cppreference page](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj4ydX1rJPdAhVBwZ8KHfbfCbwQFjACegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.cppreference.com%2Fw%2Fcpp%2Flanguage%2Foperator_precedence&usg=AOvVaw3eamnEOW0bOP2kMaWdB_PJ) as the first result.

Comment: ^ That and be aware of integer division.

Comment: Integer division?  The page you gave me is too complicated for me! Can you explain it to me like I'm stupid.. because I sure do feel stupid right now.

Comment: My question is: Does my code have to follow PEMDAS? my formulas? do I need to rearrange them in order for them to work?

Comment: @Ebeli The page does seem complicated, but take it slow and read carefully. You see this massive table with a lot of information. So, understanding the very first sentence (it says this is a table of precedence and associativity for C++ operators), skip to the bottom of the table. If you read carefully from there to the Notes section carefully, we can see that it gives some examples and gives the rules needed to take an arbitrary C++ expression and get the order of operations on it

Comment: Prof. Bergman explains why PEMDAS is misleading: https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/misc/numbers/ord_ops.html#:~:text=From correspondence with people on,%2C Division%2C Addition%2C Subtraction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) cppreference page contains the order of all operations in c++. It's a bit hard to digest all at once, but for simple mathematical operations you are concerned about row #5 and #6.

So yes, you can say that C++ somewhat follows PEMDAS, except, it doesn't have an exponent operator (see [std::pow](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)). But to clarify, multiplication and division are of the same priority (evaluated left to right) so are addition and subtraction (also left to right)

Assuming you mean in `5/9 * (34/.2)` that `5/9` is a fraction, or in other words, the `(34/.2)` is not in the denominator, `5/9 * (34/.2)` and `(34/.2) * 5/9` should in theory evaluate to the same thing, right?

The reason they don't is because of integer division. When you write `5/9` what you should get is 0.555556, but because both 5 and 9 are integers, the / operator returns only the integral part of the result, in this case 0. However, when you evaluate the brackets first, you start by dividing an integer by a non-integer value (in this case, double). This returns a double result which when multiplied by 5 gives another double result, and dividing it by 9 doesn't do the integer division (because the first operand is double).

To reclarify the fault is not that the order is *wrong*, it's because of unexpected integer division. You can fix this problem by changing 5 into 5.0. This way, it's a double value and the / operator will never do integer division.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. I was using int, it works with double. I hadn't realized that there's no E in c++

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is "Yes" C++ follows the standard order of precedence.

I would note that in PEMDAS the E stands for "exponent" and there is no way to express that in C++ you need to make a function call to achieve it but the rest is correct.

```
Definition:

P       Parathasis first.
E       Exponent second.
MD      Multiplication and Division third  (have the same precedence)
AS      Addition and Subtraction    fourth (have the same precedence)

MD happen left to right
AS happen left to right
```

> 5/9 * (34/.2)
>
> it will have a hard time computing this formula due to the fact that the parentheses are at the end and not the front. Is this correct?

Wrong. The above expression is well define in maths and in C++ and has the same meaning.

> (34/.2) *5/9
>
> my formula works. Any tips, pointers, guidance is appreciated.

These are not the same expression. Multiplication and division have the same precedence and are applied left to right. You have changed the order of how these operators are applied. But you say they are supposed to be associative (i.e. order is not important). That is true. But you also have to throw in the type information. One easy thing to forget is that integer division is not what you expect (it throws away the remainder).

Version 1:

```
 5/9 * (34/.2)
 34/.2   => P1       170.0
 5/9     => P2       0      // Integer division
 P2 * P1 => P3       0
```

Version 2

```
 (34/.2) *5/9
 34/.2    => P1      170.0
 P1 * 5   => P2      850.0
 P2 / 9   => P3       94.4
```

Comment: This makes so much sense! Thank you. We were getting 0s and I was a bit confused, but the way you laid it out explains it nicely and simply.